# Steam sterilization of whey in a bioreactor

Tags: chemical-engineering, process-engineering, steam

I'm trying to design a bioreactor to produce citric acid with whey and Aspergillus Niger.

The first step in the process would be to put whey into the reactor with some dextrose (approx. 10%). Then, this solution should be sterilized, and I was thinking of using batch steam sterilization by direct injection of the steam in the reactor.  The sterilization should be done at 121°C.

I'm not sure how to calculate the sterilization time and the amount of steam required for a given reactor volume (approx. 600 m<sup>3</sup>).  I was thinking of calculating it as if I had a 600 m<sup>3</sup> autoclave, but I doubt the approximation holds. In that case, the death kinetics would be given by the [Arrhenius equation](http://www.rpi.edu/dept/chem-eng/Biotech-Environ/Projects00/sterilize/batch.html):

$$
 k = Ae^{\frac{-E}{RT}}
$$

I'd need to determine the activation energy, $E$, the pre-exponential factor $A$, or some approximation for $k$. Then, I'd just have to integrate the equations for the heat and hold energy required:

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla heat &= ln(\frac{N_0 V_0}{N_1 V_1}) = \int_{t_0}^{t_1} k(t) dt \\
\nabla hold &= ln(\frac{N_1 V_1}{N_2 V_2}) = k(t2_-t_1) dt
\end{align}
$$

To figure out $t_1$ and $t_2$.

Am I approaching this problem correctly?

Comment: Do you know the SAL you need? My process engineering handbook goes into this, but only briefly and I want to think about it a bit before I give a wrong answer.

Comment: Sterilization can be achieved both with temperature and pressure. Maybe you should investigate the pressure side of the question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on the sterilization level you want to achieve. As you say, you would need to know the death kinetics parameters, or equivalently the log-decimal reduction time (D) and how it changes with temperature (Z). As sterilization is a problem that takes place almost everywhere in food industry, a standard sterilisation cycle lasts for 30 min. at 121 degC at the cold spot of your reactor. This ensures that the spores of many *Bacillus*, *Clostridium* and other thermophilic microorganisms cannot survive.
For a 600 m3 reactor the easiest is to have a temperature probe inside of the reactor.
As how much steam? That depends on how well isolated your reactor is. 
The best is to make a feedback loop with setpoint 121 degC that would send steam whenever temperature starts to drop. Otherwise, you can try to do the same manually.